# How can I calculate the average price from the previous day, filtering by groups?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have been trying to perfom a dax calculation without success. My objective is to obtain the average of the column [Média de Preco] considering some filters, which I was able to do with the code bellow.

[image]

```html
MediaPB_Band_AI_Dia = 
CALCULATE(
    dPBomba_AI_FL[.PBomba_Medio];
    ALLEXCEPT(dPBomba_AI_FL;
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Data Coleta];
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Área de Influência];
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Combustivel];
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Bandeira]
    )
)
```

The problem is that I need to also calculate for each row the same expression considering the previous day. That means: to obtain the average price of a set of filters, but filtering not the day expressed in the same row, but the equivalent of the previous day.

I have already tried some codes, without sucess, like:

```html
∆PBMedio%_Dia = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(dPBomba_AI_FL[Média de Preco]);
    dPBomba_AI_FL[Data Coleta]-1;
    ALLEXCEPT(
        dPBomba_AI_FL;
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Área de Influência];
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Combustivel];
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Bandeira]
    )
)
```

Could you please help me accomplish this?

Thank you,

Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a variable for the date:

```
∆PBMedio%_Dia = 
var dateYesterday = MAX(dPBomba_AI_FL[Data Coleta])-1
return
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(dPBomba_AI_FL[Média de Preco]);
    dPBomba_AI_FL[Data Coleta] = dateYesterday;
    ALLEXCEPT(
        dPBomba_AI_FL;
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Área de Influência];
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Combustivel];
        dPBomba_AI_FL[Bandeira]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just made an adjustment and it worked! If I were to use MAX(), I'd get the average from the last day of the time series, so I simply removed it, and it was alright. Do you mind sharing why using variable changes the calculus?

Comment: Apart from making your code more readable and easy to maintain the main advantage of variables in dax is that they are evaluated in the context in which they are defined, not the context that they are used in. This might help you: [sqlbi: variables in dax](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/variables-in-dax/)